# GIDSignIn silently signs in after signing out

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I have my iOS app set up to allow users to sign in with Google Plus. Here is how I do that:

```
GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.uiDelegate = self;
```

Then, when they want to sign out, I call this:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
```

However, when they open the app again, I call a function to sign them in silently (if they are already signed in):

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
```

and this signs them in silently even after they signed out.

So, what's happening is...

```
1. User signs in
2. User signs out
3. User resets app
4. User is silently signed in
```

I wouldn't expect them to be silently signed in if they logged out. Is there something I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may call 
`[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect]`
After signing out to remove the user's information, tokens and disable his account.